# C# WCF gzip compression IIS can't get svc/gzip working (using CloudFlare)

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a C# Winforms client that connects to WCF Services. This is working perfect in two servers. But now I created a new server, having exactly same code, same web.config, etc, and by some reason the `gzip` is not working as expected but the problem is in IIS configuration for sure.

The way it has been working is that if you add `/gzip` at the end of the endpoint URL then it will compress the response.

For example in my Winform app I have extended my WCF Services reference so we can add the `/gzip` to the endpoint like this:

```
this.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(AppState.WCFServiceUrl + "util.svc/gzip");
```

As I said this is working perfect on two servers, so is not client or server. Is something missing in the new server configuration or something and is breaking my head.

So on the server where is **NOT WORKING**, if you enter just the endpoint with .svc it works fine:

[image]

If you add `/gzip` you get that 404 error, and this shouldn't be happening.

[image]

In the server that **WORKS** you get this 400 Bad request and this way it works perfect for the client:

[image]

Any clue where could be the missing configuration or something? By the way, all of the servers have dynamic compression enabled, etc.

**UPDATE**

I think my problem is in the server web.config

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="Services.UtilBehavior" name="Services.Util">
        <endpoint address="gzip" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IUtil" binding="customBinding" contract="Services.IUtil">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
```

I think this could be an issue existing here since long time ago where I have: `endpoint address="gzip"`, If I change to `address=""` then no need to send the extra `/gzip` after the endpoint URL from client.

Comment: Compression Encoder in WCF can use gzip to compress the response. For more information about Compression Encoder, you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-compression-encoder

Comment: Why add /gzip at the end of the endpoint URL, it will compress the response. What did you configure in IIS?

Comment: Hi, I don’t remember why adding /gzip at the end does the compression. I did this like 7 years ago :) . Is this not something common right? The compression should be activated es without sending gzip at end correct?

Comment: I also remember that I didn’t do anything special to IIS to support this /gzip. I will try to get rid of it and make it work just with calling the útil.svc without /gzip

Answer (score 0):

So this was just crazy, spent almost 20 hours without stop (no joking, without stop, not lunch nothing just water) trying to figure out the issue and here is the solution just in case someone gets into the same problem.

First, the `/gzip` was not correct, even if it was working on the other servers was not the right way. So I used to have in the server `web.config` for the endpoints:

```
<endpoint address="gzip" ....
```

I changed to:

```
<endpoint address=""  ....
```

This was not the main issue just was a general fix. The real issue was super simple to fix but took 20 hours to figure out. How I figure it out?

First I enabled diagnostic to my WCF services by adding this into my `web.config`:

```
diagnostics>
                         <messageLogging maxMessagesToLog="30000" 
                                 logEntireMessage="true" 
                                 logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
                                 logMalformedMessages="true" 
                                 logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true">
                         </messageLogging>
                 </diagnostics>

  </system.serviceModel>


<system.diagnostics>
                 <sources>
                         <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                                 switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing" 
                                 propagateActivity="true" >
                                 <listeners>
                                         <add name="xml" />
                                 </listeners>
                         </source>
                         <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" 
                                 switchValue="Verbose">
                                 <listeners>
                                         <add name="xml" />
                                 </listeners>
                         </source>
                 </sources>
                 <sharedListeners>
                         <add name="xml" 
                              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                               initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
                 </sharedListeners>
                 <trace autoflush="true" />
         </system.diagnostics>
```

Then from my client again I tried to consume the service having same error and went to server to check the `Traces.svclog` file content. What I found there was this:

```
 Severity="Error"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelMessageReceiveFailed.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found.
```

So It matches kind the same exception receiving in the client. Then I change all to not use SSL, so changed the endpoints to use only http on client `app.config` and server `web.config` and it worked.

So the issue was in the SSL, the SSL Im using in this new server was generated by using a win-acme tool for generating Let's Encrypt certificates and I setup CloudFlare as the DNS and Network manager. So, I tried to look into CloudFlare if I had some Filter that was rerouting wrongly the requests or other stuff and found this:

[image]

The SSL Encryption mode was in `Flexible` mode, then I changed to `Full` and Voila!!!! 20 hours of spending tyring to figure out an issue thinking that was WCF server configuration and was just this simple SSL Encryption selection. Was the first time I used `CloudFlare` so Im a newbie. Hope this answer could help any other person that might get into this horrible, exhausted situation.